# REACT - Boolean flag if a condition is valid using Regex

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-hooks

I want to set a boolean flag if the `proof` text contains a valid URL in it. I'm using Regex (http:// or https:// or www. are valid urls)

```
const TabContent = ({ name, typeProof }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [proof, setProof] = useState("");
  const [inputURL, setInputURL] = useState("");
  const [valid, setValid] = useState("false");
  const isValidURLRegex =
    "([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?";

  // http:// or https:// or www. should work
  const validateURL = (value) => {
    if (!isValidURLRegex.test(value)) {
      setValid(false);
    } else {
      setValid(true);
    }
  };

  function onChange(e) {
    setInputURL(e.target.value);
    validateURL(e.target.value);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <TextInput
          style={{
            height: 50,
            margin: 12,
            borderWidth: 0.5,
            padding: 10,
            borderRadius: "10px"
          }}
          placeholder="Enter your proof here:"
          multiline={true}
          onChangeText={(value) => setProof(value)}
          value={proof}
          error={inputURL}
          onChange={() => setInputURL((error) => !error)} // or  onChange={onChange}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

export default function Tabs({ data }) {
  return (
    <TabsComponent forceRenderTabPanel>
      ...
      </TabList>
      {data.map(({ name, typeProof }) => (
        <TabPanel key={name}>
          <TabContent {...{ name, typeProof }} />
        </TabPanel>
      ))}
    </TabsComponent>
  );
}
```

Here is my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-do-i-display-specific-data-from-json-that-fullfill-a-condition-forked-z37eu1?file=/test.jsx:0-1478)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using `URL` to check if URL is valid, instead of RegExp parsing:

```
const checkIsValidUrl = (url: string): boolean => {
  try {
    new URL(url);
    return true;
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
};
```

And then you can use it in React component:

```
const isValidUrl = checkIsValidUrl(inputURL);
```

You can also memoize it, but it is a premature optimization, which is not suggested.

```
const isValidUrl = useMemo(() => checkIsValidUrl(inputURL), [inputURL]);
```

---

If you want to allow http and https protocols only, you can update the utility this way:

```
const checkIsValidUrl = (url: string): boolean => {
  try {
    const { protocol } = new URL(url);
    return protocol === 'https:' || protocol === 'http:';
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
};
```

---

If you really want to keep the flag in state, then you should use an effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const isValidUrl = checkIsValidUrl(inputURL);
  setValid(isValidUrl);
}, [inputURL]);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried something else in `Tabs.jsx` [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-do-i-display-specific-data-from-json-that-fullfill-a-condition-forked-z37eu1?file=/src/Tabs.jsx) because it doesn't seem working your answer (I should miss something I guess) but now I get `Invalid URL` whereas I have enter nothing yet...

Comment: Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-do-i-display-specific-data-from-json-that-fullfill-a-condition-forked-o8ug4u?file=/src/Tabs.jsx)

Comment: Hi, only links beginning with http:// or https:// work. I thought that using `URL()` will check if the entire url is valid whereas it begins with http/https or not (because www. or google.com is not working then...)

Comment: It's a matter of function implementation. You can implement it whatever you want. You can use your regexp, but would avoid it if possible, since it drastically reduces code readability.

Comment: You can also use my function proposal like this: `const isValidUrl = checkIsValidUrl(proof) || checkIsValidUrl('http://' + proof);`

Comment: Why do you add `|| checkIsValidUrl('http://'+proof)` if it's already working for `http://` and `https://`. I tried with  `|| checkIsValidUrl('www.'+proof)` but it doesn't work

Comment: Because [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) requires protocol to be specified. If `checkIsValidUrl(proof)` returns `true`, that means that protocol is there and we are fine, otherwise we try to "fix" url by prepending a protocol and then check the url again. If it still fails, that means that user provided an invalid url.

Comment: Why do you check `www` at all? Url can have any subdomain, not just www.

Comment: yeah you're right! I guess checking the protocols are enough